# Smart Slide show Software

Tags: image, slideshow

I am looking for a slideshow software that can also query external sources to fetch data, I have tried googling but couldn't find anything useful. Just wondering if anyone is aware of any such tool out there? :)

Regards,
Sameer

Comment: If you're looking for a software recommendation, you probably want to try the Super User site instead.  Good luck.

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for replying. I have not code or tried anything yet. I am more after a software suite or something that may have the ability to query say for example a web page and get images or a network folder based on certain conditions. If there isn't anything like this then obviously I'll have to code something. Hope this makes sense?

Cheers,
Sam